# Progress 4GL: How to convert an xml serialized table to a dataset?

Tags: xml, dataset, progress-4gl, openedge

I am accessing a method of a soap webservice, it is responding me the following result.

```
<ExportTableDataResponse xmlns="http://sisteplant.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ExportTableDataResult>
        <root xmlns="">
            <table name="Search">
                <r>
                    <c name="c0">1</c>
                    <c name="c2">05/09/2014 10:23:00</c>
                    <c name="c3">05/09/2014 00:00:00</c>
                    <c name="c5">PRE</c>
                    <c name="c6">0</c>
                    <c name="c7">1</c>
                    <c name="c8">0</c>
                    <c name="c9">m0000p</c>
                    <c name="c10">ALM06</c>
                    <c name="c11">A1</c>
                    <c name="c12">1,0000</c>
                    <c name="c13">1000,00000</c>
                    <c name="c14">PRE</c>
                    <c name="c15">1</c>
                    <c name="c17">0</c>
                </r>
        </table>
    </root>
</ExportTableDataResult>
```

I tried to convert the xml for a dataset using the following code but not work. I using the version 10.2b of progress

```
   DEFINE TEMP-TABLE MessageTypeCode NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME 'r'
    FIELD NAME                 AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "Attribute"
    FIELD ElementValue         AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "Text"
    FIELD c_recid AS RECID     XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden".

DEFINE DATASET ReceiverInfo XML-NODE-NAME 'table'
      FOR  MessageTypeCode.

DATASET ReceiverInfo:READ-XML("file", "c:\temp\resultado-pesquisa.xml", "empty", ?, FALSE, ?, "IGNORE") NO-ERROR.

FOR EACH MessageTypeCode:
    DISP MessageTypeCode.ElementValue FORMAT "X(30)"
         MessageTypeCode.NAME
         MessageTypeCode.c_recid.
    PAUSE.
END.
```

Then someone has some sujestion how I can convert this xml for a dataset?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define all "levels" of the dataset as separate TEMP-TABLEs and also you need to define their relations in the dataset as "NESTED".

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttExportTableDataResult NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "ExportTableDataResult"
    FIELD c_recid AS RECID XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttRoot NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "root"
    FIELD c_recid AS RECID XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden"
    FIELD xmlns   AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "Attribute".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttTable NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "table"
    FIELD tablename AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "Attribute" XML-NODE-NAME "name"
    FIELD c_recid   AS RECID XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttR NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME 'r' 
    FIELD c_recid AS RECID     XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttMessageTypeCode NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME 'c'
    FIELD cName                AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "Attribute" XML-NODE-NAME "name"
    FIELD ElementValue         AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "Text"
    FIELD c_recid AS RECID     XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden".

DEFINE DATASET dsReceiverInfo XML-NODE-NAME 'ExportTableDataResponse'
    FOR  ttExportTableDataResult, ttRoot, ttTable, ttR, ttMessageTypeCode
    DATA-RELATION dr1 FOR ttExportTableDataResult, ttRoot RELATION-FIELDS(c_recid, c_recid) NESTED
    DATA-RELATION dr2 FOR ttRoot, ttTable RELATION-FIELDS(c_recid, c_recid) NESTED
    DATA-RELATION dr3 FOR ttTable, ttR RELATION-FIELDS(c_recid, c_recid) NESTED
    DATA-RELATION dr4 FOR ttR, ttMessageTypeCode RELATION-FIELDS(c_recid, c_recid) NESTED
    .

/* Removing NO-ERROR - so it will crash instead if there's an error! */
DATASET dsReceiverInfo:READ-XML("file", "c:\temp\dataset.xml", "empty", ?, FALSE, ?, "ignore") .

FOR EACH ttMessageTypeCode:
    DISP ttMessageTypeCode.ElementValue FORMAT "X(30)"
         ttMessageTypeCode.cName
         ttMessageTypeCode.c_recid.
END.
/* Saving the dataset for comparison (you will see that some root-level data is missing) */
DATASET dsReceiverInfo:WRITE-XML("file", "c:\temp\dataset_new.xml") .
```

Comment: His answer already given me a direction to get the result. Thank you!

Comment: nice - xml-node-type "Text" was the secret.

Answer (score 1):

Progress expects XML for read-xml() to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tt_sample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tt_sampleRow>
    <f1>1</f1>
    <f2>abc</f2>
  </tt_sampleRow>
</tt_sample>
```

A sample program that creates XML that read-xml():

```
define temp-table tt_sample
  field f1 as integer
  field f2 as character
.

create tt_sample.
assign
  f1 = 1
  f2 = "abc"
.

buffer tt_sample:write-xml( "file", "sample.xml" ).
```

Answer (score 0):

With a correctly modelled dataset you can:

```
define temp-table tttable serialize-name "table"
   field itable as int xml-node-type "hidden"
   field name as char xml-node-type "attribute"
   .

define temp-table ttr serialize-name "r"
   field itable as int
   field irow as int xml-node-type "hidden"
   .

define temp-table ttc serialize-name "c"
   field itable as int xml-node-type "hidden"
   field irow as int xml-node-type "hidden"
   field name as char xml-node-type "attribute"
   field cvalue as char xml-node-type "text"
   .

define dataset ds serialize-name "ExportTableDataResponse"
   for tttable, ttr, ttc
   data-relation for tttable, ttr relation-fields ( itable, itable ) nested foreign-key-hidden
   data-relation for ttr, ttc relation-fields ( itable, itable, irow, irow ) nested foreign-key-hidden
   .

create tttable. assign tttable.itable = 0 tttable.name = "Search". 
create ttr. assign ttr.irow = 0.
create ttc. assign ttc.name = "c0" ttc.cvalue = "1".
create ttc. assign ttc.name = "c1" ttc.cvalue = "05".

def var lcc as longchar. 

dataset ds:write-xml( "longchar", lcc, true ).

message string(lcc) view-as alert-box.
```

output:

```
---------------------------
Message
---------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExportTableDataResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <table name="Search">
    <r>
      <c name="c0">1</c>
      <c name="c1">05</c>
    </r>
  </table>
</ExportTableDataResponse>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```